# Stitching Several Images Together Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing

I'm currently coding a game that makes use of Google Maps' Static API - http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/ However, a limitation of the API means that I can only get a maximum of 640x640 images from it and I need much larger images for my game.

As such I'm just wondering if it's possible to stitch multiple smaller images into one bigger image using Javascript?

Thanks,

DLiKS

Comment: What is your environment where you want to stitch those images? Server? Or seems to be browser? If browser, what kind of game are we talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are just trying to display them visually, then just put them in a table with no padding/margin.

If you really need them together in a single object, then use HTML5 Canvas and drawImage.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Canvas
- http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html-5-canvas-the-basics/

Answer (score 0):

I had seen one which uses OpenLayers, check it out if it is useful for you...  http://www.geoext.org/